# Help with 3D modeling

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I'm new to blender, but I've gone through the Blender Guru video series and did all that fun stuff.

So I've set out to make a mod for Fallout 4, but I've run into a couple of issues with my mod that I'm hoping someone here can help with.

So my goal is to overhaul all the bullets, cases, and cartridges with HD versions and so far it's going good, but there are a couple of aspects of my meshes I wish to improve on.

So first off, how would I go about making the type of crimp goorves seen in this bullet? I'll add a comparison of my high poly mesh as well for comparison. The crimp is very complicated and I'm not sure what method I could use to replicate it in my mesh.
[image: bullet crimp]
[image: bullet mesh]

Comment: Please keep only one question per post. Make as many as necessary.

Comment: Sorry, edited the post.

Comment: Is this to be baked back to lo-res?

Comment: The mesh will have to be low res using the Normal maps to add any extra high poly details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a black and white Displacement Map in image editing software.

[image]

Add six Edge Loops <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Then select the two inner Edge Loops and Scale them in press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to keep them from moving on the "Z" axis.

[image]

Using Cycles create a new material and bring the Displacement Map in to the Image Texture Node (Set this to Non Color Data).

[image]

UV Unwrap your bullet using Cylinder Projection. Open your Displacement image then Scale and position the UV Map to fit the image.

[image: UV Map]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added the .blend file with packed Displacement image.